# Send array through Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I want to send an array to PHP through Ajax.

```
array = $('.def-mask :checkbox:checked').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/battle.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { playerReady: 1, attack: attack, defence: array },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

But when I do `var_dump($_POST['defence'])`, I get `string()`, and not `array()`.
Why do I get a string, and not an array?

Comment: you need to json_decode(array)..??

Comment: Have you maybe forgotten to append `[]` to the name of your checkboxes? I don't know if jQuery deals with that automatically, I think it does...

Comment: Do `console.log(decodeURIComponent($.param({ playerReady: 1, attack: attack, defence: array }));` and see how your data gets actually formatted.

Comment: @pbibergal: The data is sent in the body of the request, not the header, and of course every request only contains of character data. But `json_decode` wouldn't help because the data is not formatted as JSON.

Comment: Stringify the array you are sending and json_decode serverside.

Comment: Attack is not defined.

Comment: @Matanya They are not mutually exclusive options.

Comment: When I use `json_decode()` it returns `null`

Comment: What is your actual `var_dump` of `$_POST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.serializeArray()` instead of `.serialize()`  [refer here](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)